# CumulusCI - how to run a packaging deploy with check_only false?

Tags: cumulusci

We are currently running into issues where we are not catching test failures due to the NAMESPACE issues until we try and deploy to the packaging org.

We have GitHub actions working on merging to a feature branch, but it is running the ci_feature flow.

> cci flow run ci_feature --org feature

This deployed without the Namespace, and our tests passed. Yay!

So I figured I could change this to run ci_master. But I can't deploy namespaced code to a scratch org.

My next thought is that I could run ci_master, but with
`check_only: False`

I don't understand how to accomplish this.  Do I need to copy **ci_master** from the cumulus repo?  I hoped there was a way to create a child of **ci_master** and override check_only on the deploy task.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off check-only likely won't solve your problem. If you need a namespace in a Scratch Org, you can [Link a Namespace to a Dev Hub Org](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm&type=5), and from there, you can [Create a Namespaced Scratch Org](https://sfdx-isv.github.io/sfdx-workshop/sfdx-managed-packages/create-a-namespaced-scratch-org/). From there, your deployments should work just fine.